# Redux with normlizr : unshift data to normlizr object

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization, normalizr

I have an normlizr object looks like :

```
entities:
  events:
   123: {} 
   125: {}
```

I have a new object  that i Normlized :

```
entities:
  events:
   111: {}
```

I would like to add the event to the top of the list.
how can I do that with redux && immer ?  the result in the state will look like:

```
entities:
  events:
   111: {},
   123: {},
   125: {}
```

my reducer :

```
    case ADD_EVENT: {
        draft.entities.events = action.payload.entities.events;
        return draft;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Object.assign` method or `es6` spread(...) operator

```
case ADD_EVENT: {
  //shallow merge 
  draft.entities.events = Object.assign(
                            {},
                            action.payload.entities.events,
                            draft.entities.events,
                          );

  return draft;
}
```

**UPDATE**

if `action.payload.event` is just an event something like this

```
{
  111: {}
}
```

then we can simply replace like follows

```
case UPDATE_EVENT: {
  draft.entities.events = {...draft.entities.events, ...action.payload.event};
  return draft;
}
```

Comment: @Tuz I didnt get you, the above code will give your desired output, just try once

Comment: yes, it works. I am asking about how to update an entities 

for example I update one of the entites but I want to update all entities together with the changes

Comment: yep,  update your desired entity first and then perform shallow merge, that’ll work

Comment: updated answer, check now, if you want to update only specific keys in event do let me know, thanks